# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reRenderOnLangChange')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test, transloco

In my Angular project, my unit tests fail with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'reRenderOnLangChange')
> at shouldListenToLangChanges (node_modules/@ngneat/transloco/fesm2022/ngneat-transloco.mjs:385:33)
> at TranslocoPipe.transform (node_modules/@ngneat/transloco/fesm2022/ngneat-transloco.mjs:1313:36)
> at ɵɵpipeBind1 (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:27718:22)
> at templateFn (ng:///DocumentToPrintRowComponent.js:68:34)
> at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12159:9)
> at refreshView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13392:13)
> at detectChangesInView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13617:9)
> at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13580:5)
> at detectChangesInComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13569:5)
> at detectChangesInChildComponents (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13630:9)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by importing the `TranslocoTestingModule` to my tests' setup.

More info about this module here: https://jsverse.github.io/transloco/docs/unit-testing